# Any class that extends class type

Tags: typescript

How would I declare a type that is `typeof B` **and** any class that extends `B`? I've made a type that accepts an array of classes that extends the `Component` class, but this isn't working on TSC 3.(1.4|2.1).

```js
export class Component<S> {}

export type ComponentClass = new () => Component<{ message: string }>;

export interface ComponentFlags<S> {
 imports?: (typeof Component | new () => Component<any>)[]
}

export class Message extends Component<State> {}

export class Dialog extends Component<State> {
 constructor(el: HTMLDivElement) {
  super({
   imports: [Message]
  });
 }
}
```

This then raises an error when compiled.

```
type 'typeof Message' is not assignable to type 'typeof Component'.
```

Comment: Seems to work okay: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20i%20%3D%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20B%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20(p%3A%20typeof%20B)%20%3D%3E%20p%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20raises%20an%20error%20in%20the%20TypeScript%20compiler%3A%0D%0Aa(C)%3B

Comment: That sounds better.

Comment: Code seems to be fine with TypeScript 3.2.2. No TypeScript error.

Comment: There. Just exposed a bit of the code I'm working with. Should make more sense now.

Comment: @lurker That's the code I'm working with, but I've removed stuff that doesn't relate to the question - that I don't want anyone to see yet.

Comment: That's the problem with a small code snippet. When your question says "this isn't working" what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
const a = <T extends new(...args: any) => B> (p: T|B) => p;
```

For your case:

```
export type NewComponnent = new (...args: any[]) => Component<any>;

export interface ComponentFlags<S> {
    imports?: (components: NewComponent[]) => void;
    // OR
    // imports?: (...components: NewComponent[]) => void;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to have to pass it as a generic type, though.

Comment: Don't think thats right. `Array<Component<any>>` would mean an array of `Component` instances.

Comment: @WillHoskings Fixed

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense that `new () => Component<any>` is incompatible with a constructor that takes arguments.